# El Capitan - when is the last iPhone backup?

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos, backup

### How do I tell when my last iPhone backup was?

In previous versions of iTunes

- there was a info panel available when selecting my mounted iPhone in the left sidebar

  - this panel showed all kinds of useful information!
  - for example, when the last sync/backup was!
- Now there isn't.  No info.

## Q: I've backed up my iPhone by right-clicking and choosing "Back Up."  But how do I tell when the last backup is from?

### Q: is there another place (app?) to find the iPhone's status?

For example, **Image Capture** has basically replaced Photo for managing the photos on the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The panel is still there and hasn't moved.

1. Select your iPhone in the toolbar.

   [image]
2. The latest backup times and locations are shown under Latest Backup.

   [image: Latest Backup]

The version of iTunes is independent of the version of OS X. Image Capture has by no means replaced Photos and was part of OS X long before iPhoto (the predecessor to Photos.app).

Comment: Aha!  Thanks!

I didn't know that about Image Capture.  My complaint about Photos still stands, however.  I'm glad Image Capture is there for my scenario!